# Typescript parse string dd-mm-yyyy to date

Tags: date, typescript, momentjs

I have date from datetimepicker in this format "14-02-2018". Value is string.
I must parse this value to date. I try this way:

```
new Date(Date.parse('02-03-2018))
```

But it works only if the format is 2018-03-02
In moment I can't parse too.

```
var aaa = moment(itemvalue, "DD-MM-YYYY");
```

Comment: What is the error with the `moment` call?

Comment: That `moment` call shoud work.

Comment: ... assuming `itemvalue` contains a date matching that format.  Does it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Using Moment JS

```js
var date = new Date(moment('02-03-2018', "DD-MM-YYYY"));

console.log(date.toString());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Not exactly sure why but I had to do this (in Typescript) to get something similar to work: `new Date(moment('02-03-2018', 'DD-MM-YYYY').toString())`