# How to truncate the time from the date and pass it to the component?

Tags: java, angular, typescript, date, datetime

I have this problem:

From the backend I get the date in the format: `2022-05-20`

When I want to edit the date I get an error: `Internal Server Error Text '2023-04-29T22:00:00.000Z' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 10.`

Comment: Unfortunately you didn't provide the server code which produces the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a string in your form and the service expects a date, then you need to go from string to date.

Date.parse(val: string): Date is what you need or like kind.

See this:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

or for more formats and flexibility a library:

[Typescript parse string dd-mm-yyyy to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49072720/typescript-parse-string-dd-mm-yyyy-to-date)

If it is the reverse and you have a date and need a string, then the format function you list has the signature you need.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is an Angular workspace.

If you want to format dates programmatically check this out: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-row3uy?file=src%2Fmain.ts

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, inject } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
   <p>dateOne: {{ dateOne | date : 'YYYY-MM-dd' }}</p>
   <p>dateTwo: {{ dateTwo | date : 'YYYY-MM-dd' }}</p>
   <p>dateTwo: {{ dateThree }}</p>
  `,
  providers: [DatePipe],
  imports: [DatePipe],
})
export class App {
  datePipe = inject(DatePipe);

  dateOne = '2023-04-29T22:00:00.000Z';
  dateTwo = new Date(this.dateOne);
  dateThree = this.datePipe.transform(this.dateTwo, 'YYYY-MM-dd');
}
```

Comment: you needn't use datePipe, you can use directly [formatDate](https://angular.io/api/common/formatDate): `dateThree=formatDate(this.dateOne,'YYYY-MM-dd','en-US')` or `dateThree=formatDate(this.dateTwo,'YYYY-MM-dd','en-US')`